# What is a good process/convention to use for something like transactional mail?

Tags: php, email, process, conventions

This is more of a discussion question but I would like to know what the best or a better process is for doing something like transactional mail.

Currently I am using a spooler service that runs on my server that gets run by a cron every 5 minutes to send the mails that exist in the queue. But this is too slow. I am talking about the process.

1. Transactional mail (definition) :
   Emails, Texts that are sent to the
   user of the application for reminders, notifications, warnings, upgrade info etc.

The current process is something like this:

- The application builds a mail object
  with the relevant information.
- The mail then gets sent to the smtp server to as a mail file.(yes a whole file) to reside in a queue.
- A cronjob runs over it to capture all the mail files and actually sends them off to a MTA server for sending.

  I think this process is a bit too complex and would like to hear anybody's thoughts on it. Notifications and reminders are better when they are instant is it not?

Regards

Comment: Why cannot the application send the mail directly to the MTA?

Comment: because as part of the security I do a whole bunch of additional checks on it. Spam checking and content semantic tagging and so forth. Also, To give a outsider access to your whitelisted MTA server is a BIG risk won't you say? My application also personalizes a message with the contact's details existing on my app server so they just create the mail with some tags in. Hope that explains it better?

Comment: Really, no one would like to set their views here?

Comment: You apparently have what you perceive to be a whole lot of constraints which you don't mention in your post - however your proposed approach is fundamentally flawed in several regards - Anders is correct. Writing directly to the mail queue is absurd. Trying to manage a mailq via cron (assuming that you're not using dial-up internet access) is absurd. An SMTP server **is** an MTA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good application that does this:

http://postmarkapp.com